# Ruby gems installation error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

When I am trying to install a gem or run anything with gem command, I see this warning,

```
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/ender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-0.9.0/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": undefined method `first' for #<String:0x007ffedc0964f0> (NoMethodError)
```

I searched it but I could not find anything out.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Note: I cannot install any gems.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you update your Ruby version without updating the gem version, by any chance?

Comment: i tried gem update --system but i saw the same error.

Comment: you right. i downgraded my ruby version which was 1.9.3. However how can I use my gems with ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 5):

Try removing the `/Users/ender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-0.9.0` directory. There seems to be a problem with this gem.

Comment: i removed it but now when i am trying to install taco gem. i saw Fetching: taco-0.0.1.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Users/ender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/cache/taco-0.0.1.gem

Comment: This new error is because your user doesn't own that directory that it's trying to write to. I would recommend using `sudo` to change the permissions there or imploding RVM and starting again.

Comment: yeah your right as well. i imploded my RVM and now i set it again without sudo but i saw same error when i was trying to install sqlite3 or rails on rvm